# Find an other addition $\dotplus$ on $\mathbb{R}$ so that $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with $\dotplus$ and regular scalar multiplication is a vector space.

Tags: vector-spaces

I was wondering if you could find an addition $\dotplus$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ different than the regular addition $(x;y)+(x';y')=(x+x';y+y')$ so that $(\mathbb{R};\dotplus;\cdot)$ is still a vector space. The scalar multiplication is the regular one on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I first tackled this question thinking it would be pretty easy to find one, but I've actually failed at it (notably because the existence of the identity seems pretty restrictive). We can easily show that if we find such an addition on $\mathbb{R}$, it would work on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as well, but I'm pretty sure it's impossible to find one on $\mathbb{R}$, therefore, it doesn't help us much.

I'm thinking more and more that the regular scalar multiplication implies a unique addition, a bit like the commutativity of the first operation of a ring can be deduced from the other axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be any non-linear bijection $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ that preserves distance to origin and straight lines (so it preserves scalar multiplication), for example, in polar coordinates $f((r, \phi)) = (r, \pi \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\phi}{\pi}})$ for $\phi \leq \pi$, and continue to preserve straight lines for $\phi > \pi$.

Then define $\vec a \dotplus \vec b = f^{-1}(f(\vec a) + f(\vec b))$. It's easy to check that all vector space properties are satisfied (addition-related because $f$ is bijection, and multiplication-related because $f(\alpha \vec a) = \alpha f(\vec a)$).

It's indeed impossible in one-dimension case, because the only bijection $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that preserves scalar multiplication is multiplication by a constant (as after you know image of $1$, you know the bijection).

Comment: Is it obvious that the new addition is different from the old one? Is this implied by non- linearity?